# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, django-models

I'm trying to build a web service, but I'm stuck with my models. I have made a Model "User" and it has a ListField() as photos, "Photo" is an embedded document. But while saving this user object I get an error as :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Challenge\trial\services\workspace\Service\src\appservices\trial.py", 
  line 7, in <module>
  likedBy=["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"]))
File "E:\Challenge\trial\Python27\lib\site-packages\djangotoolbox\fields.py", 
    line 253, in __init__
    super(EmbeddedModelField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'likedBy'
```

Below is my models file:

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField, EmbeddedModelField

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique = True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    photos = ListField()        #embedded list of photos uploaded by users
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Photo(EmbeddedModelField):
    description = models.TextField()
    link = models.TextField()
    like = models.IntegerField
    likedBy = ListField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And the way I'm trying to save the User object is:

```
user = User(username="username", fname="Harshal", lname="Tripathi")
user.photos.append(Photo(description="This is a great photo uploaded for trial", link="http://image.com/images/user_photo.jpg", like="365", likedBy=["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"]))
user.save()
```

Comment: try removing code "likedBy = ListField()"

Comment: it won't work I have tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to me like nothing more than a normal Python issue.  You've subclassed from EmbeddedModelField, but you've not overridden the **init** method in your subclass.  As a result, when you instantiate that class providing arguments specific to your subclass, those are being fed directly to the base class's **init**, which is then bombing out.

At a glance at Django docs, you'll want to override **init** and process your class-specific args/kwargs and pass any generic/common arguments up to the base class (snippet from the docs below the following example).

I'm not a Django dev, and do not have time to get it installed and setup, but based on your provided code above, I would expect the following to work unless there's something inherent to Django that I'm not privy to and don't see at a glance in the docs.

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField, EmbeddedModelField

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique = True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    photos = ListField()        #embedded list of photos uploaded by users
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Photo(EmbeddedModelField):
    description = models.TextField()
    link = models.TextField()
    like = models.IntegerField
    likedBy = ListField()

    def __init__(self, link=None, like=None, likedBy=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Photo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.link = link or self.link
        self.like = like or self.like
        self.likedBy = likedBy or self.likedBy

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

> Writing a field subclass¶
>
> When planning your Field subclass, first give some thought to which
>   existing Field class your new field is most similar to. Can you
>   subclass an existing Django field and save yourself some work? If not,
>   you should subclass the Field class, from which everything is
>   descended.
>
> **Initializing your new field is a matter of separating out any
>   arguments that are specific to your case from the common arguments and
>   passing the latter to the __init__() method of Field (or your parent
>   class).**
>
> In our example, we’ll call our field HandField. (It’s a good idea to
>   call your Field subclass Field, so it’s easily identifiable
>   as a Field subclass.) It doesn’t behave like any existing field, so
>   we’ll subclass directly from Field:

```
from django.db import models

class HandField(models.Field):

    description = "A hand of cards (bridge style)"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 104
        super(HandField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This did not help. Please can you help with the example I've show above, as I tried doing what you suggested and it did no good.

Comment: Edited to add an example based on your provided code. That should work fine unless there's something wacky in Django that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Thanks.:)
Though I have changed my approach and able to achieve what I wanted to. I shall give you what you deserve for your time and efforts. :)